# php mysqli bind_params not working

Tags: php, mysqli, bind, parameters

I'm trying to get a parameterized query working with the following code:

```
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT formattributes.id as attr_id, forms.title as form_title, formattributes.label as attr_label, formattributes.description as attr_description FROM formattributes
INNER JOIN forms ON forms.id = formattributes.form_id WHERE forms.title  LIKE '%?%'");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $search);
$search = $_GET['search'];

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

However after executing the query I've checked my general_log table in my mysql database and the query  just didn't change:

```
SELECT formattributes.id as attr_id, forms.title as form_title, formattributes.label as attr_label, formattributes.description as attr_description FROM formattributes
INNER JOIN forms ON forms.id = formattributes.form_id WHERE forms.title  LIKE '%?%'
```

EDIT:

Finally got it working with the following code:

```
 $param = "%{$_POST['search']}%";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT formattributes.id as attr_id, forms.title as form_title, formattributes.label as attr_label, formattributes.description as attr_description FROM formattributes
INNER JOIN forms ON forms.id = formattributes.form_id WHERE forms.title  LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $param);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: As far as I know, the placeholder shouldn't be wrapped with quotes (`'`)

Comment: You're also binding `$search` to the statement before initialising it... and you don't really need to initialise/sanitise a new variable when using a bound parameter `$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['search'])` should probably do it (as long as you never pass `search[]` as a GET var) unless you need something like `$search = "%{$_GET['search']}%";`

Comment: <code> $stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['search'])</code> did not work. With brackets around it, it did work tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you put the placeholder wrapped with `'`, it's been threaten as a regular string and not as a placeholder.

The right way would be to wrap the variable you're binding with `%%`:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT formattributes.id as attr_id, forms.title as form_title, formattributes.label as attr_label, formattributes.description as attr_description FROM formattributes
INNER JOIN forms ON forms.id = formattributes.form_id WHERE forms.title  LIKE ?");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $search);
$search = '%'.$_GET['search'].'%';

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

**Similar questions:**

- [php mysqli prepared statement LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-like)
- [MySqli prepare statement error when used for LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229880/mysqli-prepare-statement-error-when-used-for-like)

Comment: Still not working incoming prepare statement: SELECT formattributes.id as attr_id, forms.title as form_title, formattributes.label as attr_label, formattributes.description as attr_description FROM formattributes
   INNER JOIN forms ON forms.id = formattributes.form_id WHERE forms.title  LIKE ?

Comment: Try to first declare the search variable and its value and afterwards to bind it.

Comment: Nevermind it where the brackets around the variable. Look at my edit above! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Edited accordingly. You're welcome. If my answered helped you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score -1):

change blow code.

```
 $stmt->bind_param(':s', $search);
```

**OR**

```
SELECT formattributes.id as attr_id, forms.title as form_title, formattributes.label as attr_label, formattributes.description as attr_description FROM formattributes
INNER JOIN forms ON forms.id = formattributes.form_id WHERE forms.title  LIKE '%:s%'

 $stmt->bind_param(':s', $search);
```